# How to make a selection list to null in runtime?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code that fetches a list from DB. **Using that returned array i am creating a grid table and two combo boxes dynamically**. Now, the code is working fine for first time. I can also able to add new entry to the database and show it in the grid. Now the problem is with the combo box.

Whenever i add a new entry, **the table gets updated** by deleting the previous content in the table and fetching again from the DB along with new entry. **But the combo options get appended with the newly arrived data**. See, the image. **Chemical Engg is newly addded**.[image]

But i dont know to reset or delete existing combo  box contents. I know that the solution is a piece of code that makes the combo box null. **It has to be placed on the top of combo box generation code.** **So, that it ll reset every time before generating new elements.**

My question is how to make that combo box null in the starting point.(I dont know what exact term is "null" or "reset", i new to DOM elements).

Here my Code.

The HTML ELEMENT:

```
<select id="departmentField" >//Both using same data source. 
<select id="searchDepartments">
```

**The Script:** 
Its **DWR Call...** I think the problem comes below the grid.

```
    EmployeeManagement.getDeptList(function(deptRecords) {
    $("#depts").clearGridData(true);
    $("#depts").jqGrid('addRowData', "deptID", deptRecords);

    var deptSearchSelect = document.getElementById('searchDepartments');
    var searchOptions = null;
    searchOptions = document.createElement('option');
    searchOptions.value = 0;
    searchOptions.innerHTML = "ALL";
    deptSearchSelect.appendChild(searchOptions);

    var depFieldSelect = document.getElementById('departmentField');
    var deptFieldOpts = null;
    deptFieldOpts = document.createElement('option');
    deptFieldOpts.value = 0;
    deptFieldOpts.innerHTML = "";
    depFieldSelect.appendChild(deptFieldOpts);

    for(i = 0; i<deptRecords.length; i++) { 


        var dept = deptRecords[i];
        searchOptions = document.createElement('option');
        searchOptions.value = dept.deptID;
        searchOptions.innerHTML = dept.deptName;
        deptSearchSelect.appendChild(searchOptions);

        deptFieldOpts = document.createElement('option');
        deptFieldOpts.value = dept.deptID;
        deptFieldOpts.innerHTML = dept.deptName;
        depFieldSelect.appendChild(deptFieldOpts);

    }

    deptSearchSelect.selectedIndex = "ALL";
    deptSearchSelect.selectedIndex = "";

    //var respDiv = document.getElementById("respCheck");
});
```

How shall i reset?

Any suggestions would be more appreciative

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting each element in the `select`:

```
while(deptSearchSelect.hasChildNodes()) {
    deptSearchSelect.removeChild(deptSearchSelect.firstChild);
}
while(depFieldSelect.hasChildNodes()) {
    depFieldSelect.removeChild(depFieldSelect.firstChild);
}
```

Are you also not able to set the select box properly?